# XPath query is sometimes not showing the right elements

Tags: php, xpath

I am using XPath, and this is my query:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//div/div/div/div/div/div[@id="con1"]/table/tr/td');
```

And everything works fine.

Then I change the condition in the `div`, and the query is like this:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//div/div/div/div/div/div[@id="con2"]/table/tr/td');
```

And I do see what I must see.

But later, if I do this:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//div/div/div/div/div/div[@id="con1" or @id="con2"]/table/tr/td');
```

I see again only the elements of `con1`. Why is that?

The full code is below:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//div/div/div/div/div/div[@id="con1" or @id="con2"]/table/tr/td');
foreach ( $elements as $element ) {
    $str1=$element->getAttribute('class');
    $str2="first-td";
    $str3="status";
    if (strcmp($str1,$str2)==0) {
        var_dump( $element->nodeValue);
    }
    if (strcmp($str1,$str3)==0) {
        echo $element->childNodes->item(0)->getAttribute('class'). "<br />"; 
    }
}
```

To sum up: If my condition is only `con1`, I see the correct results. If it's only `con2`, I see the correct results. The problem comes when I am using the `or`. In that case, I see the results only from `con1`. It's like it's stopping after fullfilling the first condtions. They are at the same level of the DOM tree.

Comment: And is it really necessary to have all those `div`s when you have the wildcard starter anyway?

Comment: Yes if you see if I live only the one condition, i get the results. If I use the or I am getting only the first one.

Comment: Verify how many elements are selected -- if their number is two, then the problem is caused by the PHP code, not by the XPath expression which looks correct.

Comment: Please I have written them. If condition in con2 i see what I must see. If condition is con1 I still see correct results. They are at the same level and they do exist. Separate access to each of them works.

Problem comes when I use the or in conditions. Its like stopping after fullfilling the first condition.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question... as Dimitre says, the xpath looks fine, as does the PHP... as he also says, check the length of the `$elements` array

Comment: length is 2 but it just doesnot print anything that meet the second condition

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to retrieve `<div id="con1">` and `<div id="con2">` in the same expression, but what you are actually doing is to retrieve a *div* which either has an attribute *id="con1"* or *id="con2"*. The first expression of the condition returns true and then you get the `<div id="con1">` node. It makes sense.

To get both nodes you need something like:

```
//div[@id="con1"]|//div[@id="con2"
```

Note: `//div[@id="con1"]` finds whatever node `<div id="con1">` in the tree and the `id` in a document has to be unique. It's not necessary to specify all the path down.